# How should I print this in a .bat file?

Tags: batch-file, printing

```
echo ping localhost -n 4 > nul >>TEST.bat
```

When I print this in a .bat file, for example, the "> nul" disappears. How can i just print "> nul" as a string way?

Comment: Escape it using `^`. `echo ping localhost -n 4 ^> nul >> TEST.bat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To esacpe `>` or `<` or `|` just add the carret `^`

```
@echo off
Color 0E
(
    echo cls
    echo @echo off
    echo Color 0B
    echo echo Please Wait a while ....
    echo ping localhost -n 4 ^> nul
)>TEST.bat
cls
echo.
echo Type any key to read the contents of your new batch file
pause>nul
echo.
Type TEST.bat
pause>nul
cls
echo.
echo Type any key to execute your new batch file ...
pause>nul
TEST.bat
```